# nodejs createing a "data container"

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a kind of "json data container" in Java but Im currently working in a JavaScript project and I wanted to save data like I usually do in Java: https://hastebin.com/arajusubum.cs

This is my "container" class in Java and I kind of tried to re-create it in JavaScript like this:

```
const fs = require("fs");

class Container {
    constructor(path) {
        this._path = path;
        this._storage = "";
    }

    put(key, value) {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
        this._storage[key] = value;
        console.log(this._storage);
    }

    get(key) {
        if(!this._storage.includes(key)) return null;
        return this._storage[key];
    }

    flush() {
        const jsonString = JSON.stringify(this._storage);
        fs.writeFile(this._path, jsonString, 'utf8', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("An error occured while writing JSON Object to File.");
                return console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Container;
```

But it is not working, meaning it throws no error and nothing heppens if I try to output the class object.

This is how I added it into my code:

```
const Container = require("../classes/Container");
...
...
const newContainer = new Container("./test.json");
newContainer.put("taskID", "1234");
console.log(newContainer);
```

Greetings, Linus E.

Comment: Post the code of how you're instantiating this in JavaScript as well please

Comment: you have to call `newContainer.flush()` else it wont save, also you need to load it initially else it will just overite, why are you reinventing the wheel and simply not using [conf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/conf) package or such?

Comment: Yeah I know that I have to call that, but it should still output the data I inserted even without saveing it to a file

Comment: `this._storage = "";` should be `this._storage = {};` though your get errors like `_storage.includes` is not a function, as your setting the value using an object structure but looking for it like an array

Comment: Thank you, it worked and thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That solved my problem:

```
this._storage = {};
```

Changeing `this._storage = ""` to `this._storage = {};`

Comment: Looks like you put this in as an answer, but it's not an answer to your question; instead can you edit your question to add these details?

Comment: My question was how I could fix the issue with not being able to use the inserted data of the container dan in the end that line fixed it. So thats basiclly the answer to my question. But correct me if Im wrong